# how do I enter the input to ruby program when it is running some other tool

Tags: ruby

I have a requirement where I need to run the ruby script in WINDOWS and which will have the following command

#### test.rb

Dir.chdir("C://mtn-2//mtn-2.2//bin//")
system("CadTestNode.bat")

Here am running some tool called mtn tool, once I run this program it will display the following in the output pane

CAD Message Test Node

```
Select from the following options:

m - Show Menu
c - Create Test Case Connection
a - Execute All Test Cases
t - Terminate All Test Cases
x - Terminate Test Case Connection
s - Set Sequence Number
q - Quit
```

Enter choice:

After this the script is stucked in between, its asking for the input. My question is, is there any way to provide the input via script itself? Onemore thing, here I need to provide input 2-3 times. Is it possible to automate this kind of scenario as am running some other tool from the ruby script.
Thanks inadvance, waiting for your early reply.

Answer (score 1):

Use pipe (`Open3`) instead of `system` and you will be able to read from external program as well as reply to it. Of course, for Windows you will have to install `win32-open3` from http://rubyforge.org/projects/win32utils

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gets()](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/getting_input.html) to get the input, as for the rest (automate) sure, why not. Instead of `my_input=gets.chomp` do `my_input='my predefined actions'` and parse it accordingly.